# Is it possible to save a text after clicking a button on streamlit?

Tags: python, csv, streamlit, save-as

I have

```
b0 = st.button("Hi There", key=0)
        if b0:
            st.write("gratitude word")
```

is it possible to save the output of clicking b0? so basically saving the "gratitude word" as CSV, named something like file_one.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
b0 = st.button("Hi There", key=0)
    if b0:
        st.write("gratitude word")
        with open("file.csv", "w") as f:
            print("xxx", file=f)
```

does the job.